# How do I sum a table by row and by column in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have data that looks like this:

|  | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | row | row | row |
| B | row | row | row |
| C | row | row | row |

I want to sum the values in the cells if the row starts "A" and the column header is less than 12. I tried using SUMIFS, but it keeps giving me a value error. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH to return the correct row:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(C7,A:A,0),0),B1:D1,"<"&C8)
```

[image]

Comment: Can I see the full formula? Thanks!

Comment: I put the formula as text.